# Javascript - understanding recursive inner function

Tags: javascript, json, recursion

The following code prints the path of the key searched by its value inside an object:

```js
function findKeyPath(obj, keyAttr, keyValue) {
  let path = "";

  (function findKey (obj, keyAttr, keyValue, keyPath) {

    const prevPath = `${keyPath ? keyPath + "." : ""}`;
    if (obj[keyAttr] === keyValue) {

      path = `${prevPath}${keyAttr}`;

    } else if (typeof obj === "object" && JSON.stringify(obj) === JSON.stringify(keyValue)) {

      path = prevPath.slice(0, -1); // remove last dot
    }
    if (typeof obj === "object" && !Array.isArray(obj)) {
      for (const key in obj) {

        if (Array.isArray(obj[key])) {
          for (let j = 0; j < obj[key].length; j++) {

            findKey(obj[key][j], keyAttr, keyValue, `${prevPath}${key}[${j}]`);
          }
        }
        if (obj[key] !== null && typeof obj[key] === "object") {

          findKey(obj[key], keyAttr, keyValue, `${prevPath}${key}`);
        }
      }
    }
  }(obj, keyAttr, keyValue));

  return path;
}

console.log(
  findKeyPath({
    users: [
      { name: "sam", surname: "red", age: 12 },
      { name: "sam", surname: "red", age: 42 },
      { name: "sam", surname: "red", age: 16 }
    ]
  }, "age", 16)
);
```

... it prints *users[2].age*.

Trying to taking out the inner function, like this:

```js
function findKey(obj, keyAttr, keyValue, keyPath) {
  const prevPath = `${keyPath ? keyPath + "." : ""}`;

  if (obj[keyAttr] === keyValue) {

    return `${prevPath}${keyAttr}`;

  } else if (typeof obj === "object" && JSON.stringify(obj) === JSON.stringify(keyValue)) {

    return prevPath.slice(0, -1); // remove last dot
  }
  if (typeof obj === "object" && !Array.isArray(obj)) {
    for (const key in obj) {

      if (Array.isArray(obj[key])) {
        for (let j = 0; j < obj[key].length; j++) {

          findKey(obj[key][j], keyAttr, keyValue, `${prevPath}${key}[${j}]`);
        }
      }
      if (obj[key] !== null && typeof obj[key] === "object") {

        findKey(obj[key], keyAttr, keyValue, `${prevPath}${key}`);
      }
    }
  }
}

console.log(
  findKey({
    users: [
      { name: "sam", surname: "red", age: 12 },
      { name: "sam", surname: "red", age: 42 },
      { name: "sam", surname: "red", age: 16 }
    ]
  }, "age", 16)
);
```

It prints *undefined*. How can I solve it?

**UPDATE, now it works**:

```
function findKey(obj, keyAttr, keyValue, keyPath) {

    const prevPath = `${keyPath ? keyPath + "." : ""}`;

    let path = "";

    if (obj[keyAttr] === keyValue) {
        return `${prevPath}${keyAttr}`;
    } else if (typeof obj === "object" && JSON.stringify(obj) === JSON.stringify(keyValue)) {
        return prevPath.slice(0, -1); // remove last dot
    }

    if (typeof obj === "object" && !Array.isArray(obj)) {
        for (const key in obj) {
            if (Array.isArray(obj[key])) {
                for (let j = 0; j < obj[key].length; j++) {
                    path = path.concat(findKey(obj[key][j], keyAttr, keyValue, `${prevPath}${key}[${j}]`));
                }
            }

            if (obj[key] !== null && typeof obj[key] === "object") {
                return path.concat(findKey(obj[key], keyAttr, keyValue, `${prevPath}${key}`));
            }
        }
    }

    return path;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One problem with second code snippet I can think of is, we have `path` as a variable who is getting updated throughout the `findKey` function calls, it is a sort of "protected variable" which the `findKey` function can access and modify. In second code snippet we are not modifying the variable but returning it directly to the caller, which might not return anything for this part of code

```
if (typeof obj === "object" && !Array.isArray(obj)) {
for (const key in obj) {

  if (Array.isArray(obj[key])) {
    for (let j = 0; j < obj[key].length; j++) {

      findKey(obj[key][j], keyAttr, keyValue, `${prevPath}${key}[${j}]`);
    }
  }
  if (obj[key] !== null && typeof obj[key] === "object") {

    findKey(obj[key], keyAttr, keyValue, `${prevPath}${key}`);
  }
}
```

Imagine `findKey` getting called here and returning things as per your expectation but then we are not returning anything from this function, hence the `undefined` is getting returned. We might need to introduce a variable and store results and return it for this part of code.